# (Hard) Counting problem with recurrence

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $f(n)$ be the number of integer sequences with length of n which start with $0$, end with $0$ and every two adjacent numbers in the sequence has the difference of $1$ (i.e. for every $1\leq i \leq n-1$, $|a(i)-a(i+1)|=1$, numbers can be also negative).

(a) find the formula for $f(n)$

(b) find $g(n)$ under the same conditions but with the new condition $|a(i)-a(i+1)|\leq1$ for every $i$. (Replacing the last condition of f(n))

Thanks a lot if someone can help me!

Comment: Please fix that $a(a+1)$. (There is also an $I$ instead of $i$.) Do we count finite sequences of length $n$? If the condition in the definition of $f$ is replaced, then please introduce an other notation, e.g. $g(n)$ (else people may get confused reading the answers), and the range of variation of $i$ may be mentioned. It is always good to share the own thoughts with us, e.g. examples, the value of $f(n)$ and of "the other" $f(n)$ for small values of $n$, explicit enumeration when this is handy.

Answer (score 2):

a) $f(n)$ is equal to the number of sequences of $(n-1)$ finite differences $(a_{p+1}-a_p)$ all of which must be either $=1$ or $-1$

The $(n-1)$ numbers must sum to $0$

There must be the same number of $-1$ as$+1$

This can only happen if $(n-1)$ is even

So $f(n) =0$ for even $n$

for odd $n=2k+1$ you must have $k$  plus ones  and $k$ minus ones in the sequence $2k$ of finite differences

There are $\binom{2k}k$ ways to choose where the negatives will be in the sequence

So $$f(n)= \binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}2}$$

for odd $n$

b) I think that $f(n)$ is infinite for $n>2$

****** EDIT ***

I provide my best answer for b) on the understanding that we have an integer sequence.

Let $g(n) $represent the number of sequences for which the finite differences are in the set $\{-1,0,1\}$

Each sequence of first differences must consist of ...
- $m$ positive ones
- $m$ negative ones
-  $(n-1)-2m$ zeros

for some $m$ in the range from zero to $ \lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \rfloor  $

there are   $\binom{n-1}{n-1-2m}=\binom{n-1}{2m}$ ways to place the zeros

then $\binom{2m}m$ ways to arrange the positive and negative ones

So $$ g(n) =\sum_{m=0}^{ \lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \rfloor} \binom{n-1}{2m} \binom{2m}m$$

Comment: I would guess that for b) it is expected that the sequence is one of integers...

Comment: So I guess the finite differences must be $+1$, $-1$ or $0$, that certainly changes things.